# DbUpdateConcurrencyException: The database operation was expected to affect 5 row(s), but actually affected 4 row(s);

Tags: entity-framework, inheritance, entity-framework-core, db2, .net-6.0

i'm using .net 6 and IBM.EntityFrameworkCore Version 7.0.0.200

i have a model utilizing inheritance as :

```
PARENT => PARENT_SINGLE
       => PARENT_MARRIED
```

All works for all operations and update for the inherited parent model works fine on its own but when i try to replace PARENT_EMAIL child collections off the parent via remove and add i get the following :

An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type 'DbContexts.PARENTDb2Context'.

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: The database operation was expected to affect 5 row(s), but actually affected 4 row(s); data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded.

The debugged SQL looks to have the correct number of statements in this order :

```sql
1 * update PARENT
1 * delete from PARENT_EMAIL
1 * update PARENT_SINGLE
1 * delete from PARENT_EMAIL
2 RECORDS INSERTED into PARENT_EMAIL
0 * PURPOSE as this hasn't changed
```

Select of Parent as :

```cs
_dbset.Include(f => f.Purposes)
    .Include(f => f.parentEmails)
    .Where(f => parentid.Contains(f.Id))
```

The update is done as :

```cs
_dbSet.Entry(entity).CurrentValues.SetValues(updatedEntity);
_dbSet.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

and child collection per row as:

```cs
_dbSet.RemoveRange(entity);
_dbSet.AddRange(entity);
```

use of entry over update to update

added use tptmappingstratergy and here are the Configurations

```cs
var config = modelBuilder.Entity<PARENT>();
config.UseTptMappingStrategy();
config.HasKey(p => p.Id);
config.Property(p => p.Type).HasColumnName("FAC_TYPE_CODE").IsRequired().HasMaxLength(20);
config.Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("PARENT_ID");
config.Property(p => p.BorId).HasColumnName("PARTY_ID");
config.Property(p => p.StartDate).HasColumnName("START_DATE").HasColumnType("date");
config.Property(p => p.ApplicationId).HasMaxLength(20).HasColumnName("APPL_ID");
config.Property(p => p.ProductId).HasColumnName("APPL_PROD_ID").HasMaxLength(20);
config.Property(p => p.Comments).HasMaxLength(2000).HasColumnName("ADDL_INFO_TEXT");
config.Property(p => p.CreatedOn).HasColumnName("CREATED_TSTAMP");
config.Property(p => p.CreatedBy).HasMaxLength(19).HasColumnName("CREATED_USER");
config.Property(p => p.UpdatedOn).HasColumnName("LAST_UPDT_TSTAMP");
config.Property(p => p.UpdatedBy).HasMaxLength(19).HasColumnName("LAST_UPDT_USER");
config.Property(p => p.BaseRate).HasColumnName("BASE_RATE").HasPrecision(5,2);
config.Property(p => p.MarginRate).HasColumnName("MARGIN_RATE").HasPrecision(5, 2);
config.Property(p => p.Margin).HasColumnName("STND_CR_MARGIN").HasPrecision(5, 2);
config.Property(p => p.Establishment).HasColumnName("ESTB_AMT").HasPrecision(11, 2);
config.HasMany(e => e.Purposes).WithOne(e => e.Facility).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
config.HasMany(e => e.ParentEmails).WithOne(e => e.Facility).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
config.ToTable("THE_PARENT", "SCHEMA");
```

```cs
var config = modelBuilder.Entity<PARENT_SINGLE>();
config.Property(p => p.Number).HasColumnName("NO");
config.Property(p => p.Type).HasColumnName("TYPE").HasMaxLength(20);
config.Property(p => p.PricingSector).HasColumnName("PROD_SECTOR").HasMaxLength(20);
config.Property(p => p.Permanent).HasColumnName("PERM").HasPrecision(7, 2);
config.Property(p => p.Temporary).HasColumnName("TEMP").HasPrecision(7, 2);
config.Property(p => p.ExpiryDate).HasColumnName("EXPIRE_DATE").HasColumnType("date");
config.Property(p => p.Source).HasColumnName("SRC_DESC").HasMaxLength(200);
config.ToTable("PARENT_SINGLE", "SCHEMA");
```

```cs
var config = modelBuilder.Entity<EmailContact>();
config.HasKey(p => p.Id);
config.Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("EMAIL_ID").HasColumnOrder(0).ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
config.Property(p => p.ParentId).HasColumnName("PARENT_ID").HasColumnOrder(1).ValueGeneratedNever();
config.Property(p => p.EmailContactId).HasColumnName("EMAIL_CONTACT_ID");
config.Property(p => p.EmailAddress).HasMaxLength(250).HasColumnName("EMAIL_ADDRESS");
config.Property(p => p.UpdatedOn).HasColumnName("LAST_UPDT_TSTAMP");
config.Property(p => p.UpdatedBy).HasMaxLength(19).HasColumnName("LAST_UPDT_USER");
config.ToTable("PARENT_EMAIL", "SCHEMA");
```